# TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable on NLP

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, boolean

I get error this error when im trying open some parts from pickle

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

```
filename = r"Biden_tweets.pkl"
full_text = []
with open(filename,"rb")as file:
    while True:
        try:
            tweet = pickle.load(file)
            full_text.append(tweet['retweeted']['full_text'])
            #print(tweet.keys())
        except EOFError:
            break
```

These are printed keys:

```
print(tweet.keys())
dict_keys(['created_at', 'id', 'id_str', 'full_text', 'truncated', 'display_text_range', 'entities', 'metadata', 'source', 'in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'user', 'geo', 'coordinates', 'place', 'contributors', 'is_quote_status', 'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'retweeted', 'possibly_sensitive', 'lang'])
```

When i edit my code:

```
full_text.append(tweet['retweeted_status']['full_text'])
```

I get: `KeyError: 'retweeted_status'`
But when I open :

```
tweet['retweeted_status']['full_text']'
'Barr must be held accountable - and the Biden administration must release the fully unredacted Mueller report!
```

i get output

```
{'created_at': 'Mon Dec 14 23:56:27 +0000 2020',
'id': 1338633986067795970,
 'id_str': '1338633986067795970',
 'full_text': 'RT @Amy_Siskind: Barr must be held accountable - and the Biden administration must release the fully unredacted Mueller report! 
 'retweeted_status': {'created_at': 'Mon Dec 14 23:40:32 +0000 2020',
  'id': 1338629978334826503,
  'id_str': '1338629978334826503',
  'full_text': 'Barr must be held accountable - and the Biden administration must release the fully unredacted Mueller report!'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you are trying to get the item `full_text` of a boolean value, namely `tweet["retweeted"]`

You probably want to remove `["retweeted"]` and only have:

```py
full_text.append(tweet['full_text'])
```

Comment: Why are you talking about "retweeted_status" in your answer? You want to extract the full text of the tweet correct? Then why not do as I propose?

Comment: because im took only retweeted not full tweets. that's why

Comment: It's not how it works... you can read this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: We have two diffrent full text on API tweeter. first full text we have just only re-tweeted post.  Inside retweeted status we have full_text beign a tweet.

Comment: I don't see "retweeted_status" in the keys that you printed in your post, so probably not using the right key or not using this key on the right object. Maybe you can share an example json file of one tweet?